# Replacing certain values in a pandas dataseries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to replace the location "Lobur" with "LON" as shown below:

```
dcol = data["Location"]
data['Location'] = dcol.str.title().replace("Lobur", "LON")
```

Why isn't this working, does anyone know how to do it correctly? (The title part works fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to chain the string methods, you have to insert another `.str`:

```
>>> d = pd.Series(["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"])
>>> d
0    aaa
1    bbb
2    ccc
3    ddd
dtype: object
>>> d.str.title()
0    Aaa
1    Bbb
2    Ccc
3    Ddd
dtype: object
>>> d.str.title().str.replace("Cc","RRR")
0     Aaa
1     Bbb
2    RRRc
3     Ddd
dtype: object
```

This is because `d.str.title()` returns a `Series`, but the string methods are living inside the `StringMethods` object you get via `.str`:

```
>>> d.str
<pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0x93918ec>
```

You could also do it in two lines, of course.

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply:

```
data['Location'] = data['Location'].apply(lambda x: str(x).title().replace('Lobur','LON')
```

which applies the lambda function to each value

if you want to use more complicated processing you could also define it in a function and pass that function as parameter to apply(), like that:

```
def process(x):
    x=str(x)
    return x.title().replace('Lobur','LON')

data['Location'] = data['Location'].apply(process)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following method:

```
# First get the indexes interesting to you

lobur_indexes = data.index[data['Location'].values == "Lobur"]

# then use them to modify your df

data['Location'].ix[lobur_indexes] = "LON"
```